# Trouble with re.sub when used with boundary and string containing round brackets

Tags: python, string, python-re

I have the following string and I want to replace the `(abc +0.5)*3` by `10`

`Test_String= 'I am not able to replace (abc+0.5)*3'`

I've tried the following

```py
re.sub('\\b(abc\\+0.5)\\*3\\b','10',Test_String)
re.sub('\\b\\(abc\\+0.5\\)\\*3\\b','10',Test_String)
```

But nothing seems to work and I am using boundary as I want to replace the exact match.

#### Expected Output

```
I am not able to replace 10
```

#### Actual Output

```
I am not able to replace (abc+0.5)*3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i've edit your post to show you a better question structure, learn from it for next times :) (but it was already quite good originally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may

- not double escape, `\\+` becomes `\+`
- not use word boudary `\b` as there is no word boundary next to the openning parenthesis (could keep the closing one)
- escape the dot `\.` (optional as it represents any character)

```
test_string = 'I am not able to replace (abc+0.5)*3'
res = re.sub(r'\(abc\+0\.5\)\*3\b', '10', test_string) # \b is optional
print(res)  # I am not able to replace 10
```

Comment: but how to make sure that it will be replaced only when matched exactly. For example if 

`test_string = 'I am not able to replace (abc+0.5)*3*3'


res = re.sub(r'\(abc\+0.5\)\*3', '10', test_string)


print(res)    # I am not able to replace 10*3`    which is not the desired output. In this case it shound not be replaced with 10 as it's not an exact match

Comment: @Sameer even with word boundary at the end, it doesn't change anything. What is the rule to decide wether or not rplace the content ? Having content that touches the pattern ?

Comment: the string that needed to be replaced ist found by `r"\[(.*?)\]"` (so everything with the square brackets) and then that string is replaced with some evaluated value.

Comment: @Sameer hum, where does these square bracket come from ? I don't see any anywhere

Comment: What is the rule?  Are you looking for all space-separated words that can be evaluated as an expression?  What do you do with the word "abc"?  That could be an expression.  It's easy enough to split() the line into words, then try to evaluate each word.

Comment: @azro I have posted the question only for the part I am having trouble with, as I am not having any trouble to find out the string contained in square bracket (which in this case is: (abc +0.5)*3 ) and hence have not asked in my original post.

Comment: @TimRoberts it feels my question didn't come across clearly.Let me try again, In this substring `(abc +0.5)*3` the 'abc' will be replaced with some value and the whole `(abc +0.5)*3`  is now a value (let's say 10). Now I am having trouble to replace it. and I don't want to replace it if this `(abc +0.5)*3` ist attached with something else for example `(abc +0.5)*3sameer`

Comment: I am reading between the lines somewhat.  You are asking about a very specific string of characters.  That's easy, you don't even need a regex for that.  I ASSUME you will actually be looking for more generic expressions.  Is that not right?

Comment: Thank you soo much for your replies. After exchanging thoughts with you, I have changed my approach a bit and not I am able to use the above mentioned sugessions to tackle the problem